# Beamer - Add all references in a slide at the end

Tags: beamer, bibtex

I am trying to do what should be a simple task: Add all references at once in the last slide in Beamer. I have done the following MWE, but BibTeX exits with errors and the references are not added... Maybe I don't have the `authortitle1` file? Should it be included by default?

If I try it with my own `bst` file generated with `makebst` I get multiple errors of the type

> "Undefined control sequence", "Missing number"

etc.

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty,font=scriptsize,skip=0pt,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Phenotypic variability}
\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{\cite{Waddington1959}}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is a test
        \item This is a test \cite{VanDyk1989}
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{itemize}
    \item This is a test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    {\footnotesize
    \bibliographystyle{authortitle1}
    \bibliography{TEST}
    }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`TEST.bib` is the following:

```
@article{Waddington1959,
abstract = {THE battle, which raged for so long between the theories of evolution supported by geneticists on one hand and by naturalists on the other, has in recent years gone strongly in favour of the former. Few biologists now doubt that genetical investigation has revealed at any rate the most important categories of hereditary variation; and the classical 'naturalist' theory-the inheritance of acquired characters-has been very generally relegated to the background because, in the forms in which it has been put forward, it has required a type of hereditary variation for the existence of which there was no adequate evidence.},
author = {Waddington, C H},
doi = {10.1038/1831654a0},
isbn = {0201483645},
issn = {0028-0836},
journal = {Nature},
keywords = {Genetics},
pages = {1654--1655},
pmid = {13666847},
title = {{Canalization of development and genetic assimilation of acquired characters.}},
volume = {183},
year = {1959}
}
@article{VanDyk1989,
abstract = {The way in which proteins attain and maintain their final form is of fundamental importance. Recent work has focused on the role of a set of ubiquitous proteins, termed chaperonins, in the assembly of phage and multisubunit proteins. The range of chaperonin action is unknown; they could interact with most cellular polypeptides or have a limited subset of protein partners. Included in the chaperonin family is the essential heat-shock regulated Escherichia coli groEL gene product. Over-expression of the groE operon in E. coli causes enhanced assembly of heterologously expressed ribulose bisphosphate carboxylase subunits and suppresses the heat-sensitive mutant phenotype of several dnaA alleles. It has been inferred that suppression of heat-sensitive mutations is confined to dnaA alleles and that this confinement could reflect an interaction between the groE operon products and a dnaA protein aggregate at the replication origin. We now report that multiple copies of the groE operon suppress mutations in genes encoding several diverse proteins. Our data indicate a general role for the groE operon products, the GroEL and GroES proteins, in the folding-assembly pathways of many proteins.},
author = {{Van Dyk}, T K and Gatenby, A A and LaRossa, R A},
issn = {0028-0836},
journal = {Nature},
pages = {451--453},
pmid = {2573840},
title = {{Demonstration by genetic suppression of interaction of GroE products with many proteins.}},
volume = {342},
year = {1989}
}
```

**EDIT:** If I remove `\usepackage{cite}` and use `apalike` instead of `authortitle1` it works. So my new questions are:

1. How do I know which bibliography styles I have and which I don't? I only have the following `bst` files at

> /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/

Where can I get more?

```
abbrv.bst  acm.bst  alpha.bst  apalike.bst  ieeetr.bst  plain.bst  siam.bst  unsrt.bst
```

1. How can I remove the line breaks in the reference section?

Comment: If you don't have `authortitle1.bst` you'll get an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following MWE will work, removing \usepackage{cite} and using a different style, like apalike. The icon can be easily removed as shown in the MWE. Line breaks are inherent to the style, either write the 3 lines shown in the MWE or create your own style that doesn't include line breaks using makebst.
More styles can be downloaded from http://schneider.ncifcrf.gov/latex.html for example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty,
            font=scriptsize,
            skip=0pt,
            justification=justified,
            singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

%remove the icon
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

%remove line breaks
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Phenotypic variability}
\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{\cite{Waddington1959}}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is a test
        \item This is a test \cite{VanDyk1989}
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{itemize}
    \item This is a test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]%in case more than 1 slide needed
    {\footnotesize
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{TEST}
    }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And what about your `authortitle1` style? What is the relation of this answer with your question?

Comment: authortitle1 (as well as \usepackage{cite}) was the problem, changing the style to another one solved that problem. Additional problems like removing the icon and the line breaks in the bibliography are solved as well. Any custom style generated with makebst can now be used (\usepackage{cite} gave errors before)